# Mapping local folder in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I am using Tomcat 7.0 and trying to configure a local folder so that I can access the images from there directly using a web URL. Following is the config snippet from server.xml

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    <Context path="/images" docBase="/Users/derek/Desktop/images/uploads" />
</Host>
```

However, when I am trying to access the images using URL (http://localhost:8080/images/myimage.jpg) it does not work. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Have you tried docBase="c:/Users/derek/Desktop/images/uploads"?

Comment: I am on a Mac, so cannot do c:\

Comment: Not really used a mac, is /Users/derek/Desktop/images/uploads the full path? Can you make copies of the images in a tomcat dir? Your build file can probably do the heavy lifting

Comment: It is basically UNIX. I think I should be able to map the local drive to a web URL, but I am sure I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: I think Tomcat may be considering this as a relative path. I am not sure how to specify the absolute path in a Mac.

Comment: Your path starts with a '/'; it is absolute. What happens when you browse http://localhost:8080/images/ ? Do you have any other webapp deployed/attempting to deploy under the same context ?